# value of hidden field after ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am using a ajax function in which i pass a hidden field value and according to that the value is passed on to the next file and a query runs retuning a value (html) which i update later on to that hidden field but the problem is when i use that updated value of hidden field to pass on through a variable it dosent takes the new value updated instead it takes the old value of hidden field ? can anyone help me with this

```
var pre_prod_id = $('.prod_id').val(); //old hidden field value
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "eg",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        $('.prod_id').val(html); // got updated value via ajax and updated
    }
});
var prod_id = $('.prod_id').val(); // getting new value of hidden field
alert(prod_id); // alert gives still the old value ???
$target = 'egab=' + abd + '&& abc=' + abc + '&& action=' + action + '&& prod_id=' + prod_id;
```

i have mentioned at steps what i am trying to do ? hope someone finds a solution to this.

Comment: any solution friends ? really need help with this one

Answer (score 2):

The call to $.ajax is asynchronous, so your code won't wait until a response has been received from the server before executing the second `var prod_id = $('.prod_id').val();` statement.

The only way to be sure that a piece of code will run after the response to the Ajax call has been received, and not before, is to place it inside the 'success' function.

An alternative approach (but not one I would recommend) would be to make the ajax call synchronous by setting [async : false](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). This is bad practice however, since it can make the browser unresponsive - I would recommend refactoring the code as described above.

Comment: but my rest of code does not detect the $target if i place the $target = ''; inside the 'success' function. any alternative to that  ?

Comment: I assume that the rest of your code, which needs to use $target, must also run only after the response has been received from the server? In which case you need to place all that code inside 'success' - if there is a lot of code, put it into a named function.

Comment: yes it has a lot of code and also its like a api . i am using it for many more fucntions . god knows m stuck at this one and i can't chnage a thing in the code